# Model via sculpting silhouette?

Tags: sculpting

Is there any method or tool that would allow you to adjust a model by slicing off parts of the silhouette?

Basically it would be done like this,
https://i.gyazo.com/5981439ade7a751d61f8d1a3d4f80029.mp4

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Possibly not, but why not simply adopt a sculpting workflow to smooth out the surface?